# QNetworkReply throwing SIGSEGV when finished signal emitted

Tags: c++, qt, qnetworkaccessmanager, qnetworkreply, qnetworkrequest

My application makes use of `QNetworkReply`'s for send and receiving data from a RESTful API.

There are many tutorials available for using the [QNetworkReply](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkreply.html) with [QNetworkAccessManager](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html)

Once such example which I used can be found [here](http://amin-ahmadi.com/2016/01/17/how-to-send-and-receive-json-requests-in-qt/) or even [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/61771/qnetworkaccessmanager-and-post-return)

**Basic Usage:**

// Header

```
QNetworkAccessManager *manager;
QNetworkReply *myReply;
QMetaObject::Connection conReply;
```

// Making the request

```
void MainWindow::makeRequest(QString url) {
    //...
    QNetworkRequest request(QUrl(url));
    myReply = manager->get(request) // or post(request)
    conReply = QObject::connect(myReply, SIGNAL(finished()), this,  SLOT(myReplyResponse()));
}
```

// Handling the request

```
void MainWindow::myReplyResponse(){
    QObject::disconnect(conReply);

    QByteArray data = myReply->readAll();
    // or QByteArray data = myReply->read(myReply->bytesAvailable());

    myReply->deleteLater();

    // do something with this data

    //...
}
```

Using a similar implementation, I request data every X seconds.

**Problem:**

When receiving the `finished()` signal, the code handling the reply is triggered, but when reading the data, I get a `SIGSEGV`.

This issue seems to occur at random, thus I cannot determine what triggers it.

Any suggestions would be gladly accepted.

Comment: Have you run your application through a debugger? I'd assume you are accessing memory in that data buffer that really isn't there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is probably happening is that it is delaying the order, let's say that an order is sent every second but it takes 2 seconds to replicate, after 2 seconds you have read the reply and you have deleted it from memory, when the other comes myReply is an empty pointer. What you must do is use `sender()` to obtain the replica, and it is always advisable to validate that you do not have an empty pointer:

***.h**

```
private:
    QNetworkAccessManager *manager;
```

***.cpp**

```
[...]
manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
[...]
void MainWindow::makeRequest(const QString &url)
{
    Qurl mUrl(url);
    QNetworkRequest request(mUrl);
    QNetworkReply *myReply = manager->get(request); // or post(request)
    connect(myReply, &QNetworkReply::finished, this,  &MainWindow::myReplyResponse);
}

void MainWindow::myReplyResponse()
{
    QNetworkReply *reply = qobject_cast<QNetworkReply *>(sender());
    if(reply){
        QByteArray data = reply->readAll();
        qDebug()<<data;
        reply->deleteLater();
    }
}
```

Comment: Great. It is OK (with me). Thanks!